# Casbah - parametric find or findOne do not return what is there

Tags: mongodb, casbah

I have the problem exactly as it is described in the title.

For example, if I try:

```
  val key = "myKey"
  val value = "myVal"

  val one = Option(collection.findOne(MongoDBObject(key -> value)))
  val all = collection.find(MongoDBObject(key -> value))
```

then I check the contents and:

```
  println(one)        =>    None
  println(all.size)   =>    0
```

however, if I do not use the MongoDBObject parameter, it works - it finds all the stuff that is there.

What am I doing wrong? I assume that the parameter object specifies a `key-value` criteria that should make the search return only results that contain those `key-value` pairs...

And I have to say that the key and the value are valid. The value, however, is numeric, but in it is stringified for these statements, so should be no problem. Or not?

**UPDATE:**

While trying to capture the data necessary for more precised description of the problem, I have run tests sufficient to realize the origin of the problem. It turns out that Casbah does not leave "1" to remain a `String`, it automatically casts it into an `Integer`, and thus, comparing a String with an Integer, surely never returns `true`. Ok, so I can think of solving the problem like this:

```
def getObjectBy(key: String, value: String) = {
  val all = collection.find()
  val buffer = Buffer[DBObject]()
  while(all.hasNext) { buffer += all.next }
  val haveTheKey = buffer.filter(_.keySet.contains(key))

  if(haveTheKey.size > 0) {
    val one = haveTheKey(0)
    val v = one.get(key)

    // 1st way (hell)
    v match {
      case i: Int => if(i == value.toInt) Some(one)
      case s: String => if(s == value) Some(one)
      case f: Float => if(s == value.toFloat) Some(one)
      //... and so on..
      case _ => None
    }

    // 2nd way (better?)
    if(v.toString == value) Some(one) else None

  } else None

}
```

but that is rediculous... I suppose, that I just don't get something here, please tell me, what am I missing?

Comment: your syntax looks fine--can you post some real data from the shell, and query code? When you say stringified, do you mean the value is a string in mongodb?

Comment: Agreed the syntax is fine, perhaps the key/value is the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, finally I came up with some sort of a solution. In my situation, values can only be either decendants of `AnyVal` or the very `java.lang.String`. So the common parent would be `Any`. That is why I have changed the passed `value` type to `Any`:

```
def getObjectBy(key: String, value: Any) = {
  // ...
}
```

and it worked indeed! Doh, it was so easy! I never used `Object` in Java or `Any` in Scala, and did not think that it would work like that... but..